# Edittext set error twice

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

i have issues in EditText display twice icon on error.

[image]

xml file

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_pass"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword|textNoSuggestions"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

error icon display twice in design 24.2.0

Comment: Just remove the `editText.SetError` and apply to `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: @Ironman thanks for replay but i show  icon  error on edittext .how can it possible?

Comment: @JatinDevani don't use that because if sometime if your device is small it will hide the next `EditText` and also your `View` is not display well. So Remove from `EditText` and apply it to `TextInputLayout`. it will display good and clean `View`.

Comment: thanks @Ironman now its working i remove EditText use TextInputLayout

Comment: glad to help you.

Comment: @jatin please use TextInputLayout.SetError("your message") and textInputLayout.SetError(null);